# CentOS 7.5 losing static IP on reboot

Tags: centos, networking

I have a vm lab with CentOS 7.5 servers. There's no dhcp and each server in the lab has its IP address manually assigned. Each machine has NetworkManager stopped and disabled.

I add the IP by using `# ip addr add 192.168.1.100/24 dev ens192` followed by `# ip link set ens192 up`

Everything works fine, except when the machine reboot it loses the IP address and I have to manually set it again.

I assume there's some `systemctl` command or somethng I have to run besides these two commands that makes it permanent, but I don't know what. Hopefully you can help. Thanks

Comment: do you have a startup job that runs those commands? because their results will not be preserved across a reboot

Comment: No, I've been doing it manually after reboot so far, but I'm about to add them to rc.local as a stopgap.

Comment: In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ you should see your config file for ens192. If you vim into it, can you confirm what the ONBOOT is set to?

Comment: @ryekayo It was set to NO, and I changed it to YES and everything is good now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP command is by definition not persistent and you must put the IP addresses configuration in the `ifcfg-<connection name>` to keep it between reboots. These files are typically under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`.

You might also want to look at using NetworkManager instead, you can configure persistent network settings through NetworkManagers GUI or command-line tool, `nmcli`. See `man nmcli` for more details and examples.

Comment: Thanks, I thought IP was supposed to be used for everything relating to host networking. I edited my ifcfg script appropriately, and now I think everything is all set.